# A Visual Studio project doesn't see MySql namespace

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector

I am compiling a desktop application in Visual Studio 2010 and it cannot find MySql component. It complains in `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` directive:

```
The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

There is a reference to `MySql.Data` and MySql.Data.dll is in bin folder.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is removing the reference and re-adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. `MySql.Data.dll` was for other .NET Framework version. Replaced it with the right one.